# Pip source code string can't contain null bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to list pip packages, but when I run pip list, I get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\list.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import IndexGroupCommand
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import _inputstream
  File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import webencodings
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I thought it was just a problem with the list command and forgot about it, so I installed a pip package. However, when I put the command in, I still got the same error message. Pip was working fine before so I don't know if there's a problem with a piece of code I need to fix or something.

Comment: I would try to re-install pip; if the error persists, it can't harm to look for a null byte in PYthon files in pip/webencodings directory.

Comment: I reinstalled Pip and it worked! Thanks!